# Atualizar div em tempo real com php /javascript sem atualizar página

Tags: php, javascript

A minha dúvida é a seguinte, supondo que eu tenho uma div e nessa div tenho um código php que diz que quando alguem entra na página envia um curl. O Que quero saber basicamente é se existe alguma forma dessa div estar constantemente em atualização para mal eu mude uma coisa exiba ou de x em x milisegundos envie o curl.

Obrigado

Comment: jquery+ ajax não te ajuda?

Comment: Se soubesse aplicar

Comment: Você já fez alguma coisa pronta em código? Fica mais fácil explicar partindo de algo já feito.

Comment: Pesquise aqui na tag, vai encontrar um montão de exemplos e solução pros problemas mais básicos: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax?sort=frequent&pageSize=50

Answer (score -2):

PHP é Server Side e Javascript é Client Side. 
Não tem como rodar script php 'on the fly'.

Você precisa executar um Ajax quando quiser que essa CURL seja executada.

Veja se isso te ajuda:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
         url: "demo_test.txt", 
         success: function(result){
              $("#div1").html(result);
         }
         });
});
```